# How to replace html background image with div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I use the following CSS to display background image with Twitter Bootstrap site:

```
html {
    background:#505D6E url(/img/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    min-height:100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
         -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
}
```

I have to replace it with `div` since I can not apply jQuery animation to change one background picture to another. How should I create fullscreen div?

Comment: A div will cover to its max size by default, add on to your body tag -> ```<body><div class="page-bg"></div></body>```. This div will cover the whole page, but careful Chrome will add paddings to the body, you need to reset them. And at the end you apply the style for your html to your page-bg class. To select the right div use ```body > .page-bg```

Answer (score 1):

This creates a fullscreen div:

HTML:

```
<div id="fullscreen">

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#fullscreen{
     border:1px solid black;
     height:100%;
     width: 100%;
     position: absolute; 
     top: 0; 
     left: 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

`<div id="backgrounddiv"></div>`

```
#backgrounddiv {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: -999; // has to be below your lowest z-index
}
```

and then use `<img>` with `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` (or whatever you want) inside.